# How to easily access the information of a XML-node in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I read in an XML-file in PHP and assign it to a variable `$Xml`:

```php
$Xml = simplexml_load_file("TaskSequences.xml");
```

The XML-file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyStructure>
  <Sequences>
    <Sequence>
      <SequenceName>Sequence1</SequenceName>
      <SequencePackages>
        <Package>
          <PackageName>Package1</PackageName>
          <TargetInfo>HowToAccessThis</TargetInfo>
        </Package>
        <Package>
          <PackageName>Package2</PackageName>
          <TargetInfo>BlaBla</TargetInfo>
        </Package>
      </SequencePackages>
    </Sequence>
  </Sequences>
</MyStructure>
```

I have the following variables/information in my code:
SequenceName: "**Sequence1**"
PackageName: "**Package1**"

Based on this I want to access the corresponding information in node "TargetInfo".
As for the example above the result should be "HowToAccessThis".

Is a loop necessary? What are the easiest ways?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is worth learning a bit about XPath when using XML as it can perform quite a lot of the work for you.

This code uses `//Sequence[SequenceName="Sequence1"]//Package[PackageName="Package1"]/TargetInfo` to find the data you are after, this breaks down into...

- //Sequence - any `<Sequence>` element in the document
- [SequenceName="Sequence1"] - matches a `<SequenceName>` element whos
  text is Sequence1
- //Package - within that any `<Package>` element
- [PackageName="Package1"] - which has a `<PackageName>` element whos
  text is Package1
- /TargetInfo - and then fetch the `<TargetInfo>` element.

So the code

```
$SequenceName = "Sequence1";
$PackageName = "Package1";
echo $Xml->xpath('//Sequence[SequenceName="'.$SequenceName.'"]//Package[PackageName="'.$PackageName.'"]/TargetInfo')[0];
```

with your test data gives...

```
HowToAccessThis
```